# Unable to make a object public in bucket in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, acl, bucket

I have made a bucket with uniform access control type in GCP with an object in it. I want to make the object publicly accessible.
I am following these steps mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

1. Click on the name of the bucket that contains the object you want to make public, and navigate to the object if it's in a subdirectory.
2. Click the more actions menu () associated with the object that you want to make public.
3. Select Edit permissions from the drop-down menu.

But when I click edit permissions I get this error:
**Cannot get legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access control type of your bucket must be set to `Uniform`. This means that all objects in the bucket will have the same accessibility. In a `Uniform` bucket, you cannot set only one object to be public, you must set the bucket to be public so all objects in the bucket will be publicly accessible.

To set a single object to be publicly accessible, you should use access control type `Fine-grained` for your bucket. You will then be able to edit permissions of individual objects as you described.